# Configuring Hostname for Windows' Bash (for cx_Oracle)

Tags: python, linux, oracle

I'm on a windows machine, but am much more comfortable with bash than PowerShell. I'm trying to configure a pythonic connection to an Oracle database with the cx_Oracle package. I have a proper .py script that should be able to connect and execute a query, but receive the error 'ORA-24454: client host name is not set', which is also detailed at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167477/ora-24454-client-host-name-is-not-set-when-connecting-from-ubuntu-instance-on/169350

When I run `Hostname` from bash, I get 'DESKTOP-XXXXXXX'. When I run `Hostname -A`, I get nothing (a blank line).

I found a possible solution at the following link, but I think it is referring to an actual linux machine rather than the subsystem I'm using: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/hostname-d-returns-blank-how-to-set-domain-name-centos-6-3-a-4175443975/

Unfortunately, my subsystem is devoid of the following two directories to which the article refers: /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig. (although the /etc directory exists and has a bunch of stuff in it).

Should I create these directories, and if so can someone provide some guidance as to what to write in it? I've looked at this article but haven't tried it yet out of fear of breaking something: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap9sec93.html